# Dose Django hava a function like `abort` in Flask? I want to break a request in deal with request params

Tags: python, django

I want to dealwith request parameters in Django more elegant and here is my code：[image]

With that I can use in my view function like this:

```
def testparam(request):
name = request_get(request, 'name', required=True)
age = request_get(request, 'age', ptype=int, required=True)

print('name: ', name)
print('age: ', age)
return HttpResponse('test param run')
```

Then I ran my Django applicaiton and typed url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/param) in chrome but I still got the response with "test param run".
I want my django to make a response when request_get function called just like abort function in flask framework. Someone can help me?

Comment: `abort()` raises an exception, exiting the normal flow (so not a return); `HTTPException` is raised. Flask then handles that exception.

Comment: I don't think there is any exception in Django that could play the same role.

Comment: Note that code is **text**, don't use a screenshot for code please.

Comment: See [django: raise BadRequest as exception?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25422176)

Answer (score 0):

I sovled problem by custome the exception and exception-middleware with `Martijn Pieters` tips